# Estimate the area under the graph

Tags: calculus

We just started this topic in class and I am not quite understanding. I hope someone can guide me through this problem. 
Estimate the area under the graph of $ƒ(x)=1+x^2$ from $x=−1$ to $x=3$ using four rectangles and right endpoints

Comment: For this problem you actually don't need to find the anti-derivative. This is an estimation problem, where you draw rectangles from the x axis until the point where the right side of the rectangle reaches the line of the function. You then estimate the combined area of the triangles.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Bx^2+from+-1+to+3+using+right+endpoint+method+with+4+intervals) is really powerful nowadays. :)

Comment: @anorton I know but I want to learn how to do this problem and sometimes Wolfram Alpha does not show you

Comment: @BS319 True; I thought the picture was kind-of nice, though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Partition the interval $[-1,3]$ on the $x$ axis into 4 equal parts (so at $x=0,1,2,3$). That is, you get the intervals
   $$
   [-1,\color{blue}{0}],\ [0,\color{blue}{1}],\ [1,\color{blue}{2}],\ [2,\color{blue}{3}].\
   $$
   Since you are doing the *right endpoint method*, you will be using the *right* endpoints of each of these intervals.
2. Find the $y$ values of those *right* endpoints.
3. You have four rectangles now, with the base and height for each.
4. Calculate the area of each of those four rectangles (area = base $\times$ height).
5. Add up those four areas.

You will have found an *approximation* for $\int_{-1}^3 f(x)\,dx$.

A picture is worth 1000 words.

Comment: Thanks @JohnD
You really just made it so much easier to look at

Comment: $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,5)$, and $(3,10)$ Then you add the areas: $0+2+10+30=42$ is that correct?

Comment: Do four "base $\times$ height" calculations: $1\cdot f(0)+1\cdot f(1)+1\cdot f(2)+1\cdot f(3)=(1)(1)+(1)(2)+(1)(5)+(1)(10)=18$.